# Rhythm game finger trainer

Tags: c#, beginner, game, console, audio

Decided to make a small C# console based rhythm game finger trainer with lots of user definable options.
I'm very much a beginning programmer, so thought I might learn a lot from it. Especially when you guys could give me some advice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace _10kTrainer2point0
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
        {
            int n = array.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int r = i + rnd.Next(n - i);
                T t = array[r];
                array[r] = array[i];
                array[i] = t;
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            //assiging of the variables
            bool check = true;
            bool displayKeybinds = true;
            bool repeatOnce = true;
            string strTemp = String.Empty;
            string strTemp2 = String.Empty;
            string noteAmount = String.Empty;
            string soundEffect = String.Empty;
            string answer = String.Empty;
            string[] strArrTemp;
            List<string> strListTemp = new List<string>();
            int keyAmount = 0;
            int intNoteAmount = 0;
            int score = 0;
            int[] numbers;
            List<int> notePositions = new List<int>();
            List<ConsoleKeyInfo> keyBinds = new List<ConsoleKeyInfo>();
            List<ConsoleColor> noteColors = new List<ConsoleColor>();
            ConsoleColor backgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();

            //makes the console the size of the screen
            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 3);
            Thread.Sleep(25);

            //if the settings files already exist, read them and assign the variables to them. Otherwise go trough the settings methodes
            if (File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\values.txt") && File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\keyBinds.txt") && File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\noteColors.txt"))
            {
                //reads values.txt which has "keyAmount", "noteAmount" and "soundEffect" in it
                strListTemp = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\values.txt").ToList();
                keyAmount = Convert.ToInt16(strListTemp[0]);
                noteAmount = strListTemp[1];
                soundEffect = strListTemp[2];

                //reads keyBinds.txt, converts the lines to ConsoleKeyInfos and adds them to ConsoleKeyInfo List keyBinds
                strListTemp = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\keyBinds.txt").ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < keyAmount; i++)
                {
                    strTemp = strListTemp[i];
                    strArrTemp = strTemp.Split(' ');
                    strTemp = strArrTemp[0];
                    strTemp2 = strArrTemp[1];
                    keyBinds.Add(new ConsoleKeyInfo(Convert.ToChar(strTemp), (ConsoleKey)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ConsoleKey), Convert.ToInt16(strTemp2)), false, false, false));
                }

                //reads noteColors.txt converts the colors to ConsoleColors and adds them to ConsoleColor List noteColors
                strListTemp = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\noteColors.txt").ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < strListTemp.Count; i++)
                {
                    noteColors.Add((ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), strListTemp[i]));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //goes trough most settings
                keyAmountMethode(check, strTemp, ref keyAmount);
                keyBindMethode(ref keyBinds, keyAmount, check, answer, repeatOnce);
                noteAmountMethode(check, ref noteAmount, keyAmount);
                soundEffectMethode(check, ref soundEffect, player, answer);
                noteColorMethode(keyAmount, strTemp, ref noteColors, backgroundColor);
                valuesToFile(keyAmount, noteAmount, soundEffect, strListTemp);
                keyBindsToFile(keyBinds, strListTemp);
                noteColorsToFile(noteColors, strListTemp);
            }

            //makes a list with jumps of 5
            notePositions.Add(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < keyAmount; i++)
            {
                notePositions.Add(notePositions[i]+5);
            }

            //makes a list of numbers (0, 1, 2,...)
            numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, keyAmount).ToArray();

            if (soundEffect != "silent")
            {
                player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundEffect);
            }
            //if noteAmount is not "random" then intNoteAmount will be assigned to it. 
            //I need this because when it is, I need a different variable to not overwrite the text "random"
            if (noteAmount != "random")
            {
                intNoteAmount = Convert.ToInt16(noteAmount);
            }
            //the main program, that loops everytime certain keys corresponding to the keybinds with the indexes of the scrambled list numbers are pressed
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                if (noteAmount == "random")
                {
                    intNoteAmount = rnd.Next(1, keyAmount);
                }
                //displays the keybinds underneath the keys for reference
                if (displayKeybinds)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < keyAmount; i++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(notePositions[i] + 2, 27);
                        Console.Write(keyBinds[i].Key);
                    }
                }
                check = true;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                //displays the keybinds to change settings
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Change the key amount\n" +
                    "2 - Change the key binds\n" +
                    "3 - Change the note amount\n" +
                    "4 - Change the sound effect\n" +
                    "5 - Change the note colors\n" +
                    "6 - Change the background color\n" +
                    "7 - Toggle the keybind display");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2 - 7, Console.WindowHeight / 2 - 20);
                //displays the score(amount of times, notes have been pressed correctly)
                Console.WriteLine("Score: " + score++);
                //this schuffle makes so random notes\keybinds get chosen every loop
                Shuffle(numbers);
                //notes are basically spaces with a position and a bg color
                //here the amount given by the user (noteAmount) are created
                for (int i = 0; i < intNoteAmount; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(notePositions[numbers[i]], 25);
                    Console.BackgroundColor = noteColors[numbers[i]];
                    Console.Write("     ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                //checks if the right keybinds are pressed (key by key, because I couldn't find any better way)
                for (int i = 0; i < intNoteAmount; i++)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                    while (!(keyBinds[numbers[i]].Key == Console.ReadKey(true).Key))
                    {
                        //this is the only while loop in the main loop, so here I check if the keybinds to change settings are pressed
                        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
                        {
                            //different settings need a different amount of changes. If the user wan't to change the key amount, he will have to change a lot of other settings as well
                            keyAmountMethode(check, strTemp, ref keyAmount);
                            keyBindMethode(ref keyBinds, keyAmount, check, answer, repeatOnce);
                            noteColorMethode(keyAmount, strTemp, ref noteColors, backgroundColor);
                            numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, keyAmount).ToArray();
                            valuesToFile(keyAmount, noteAmount, soundEffect, strListTemp);
                            keyBindsToFile(keyBinds, strListTemp);
                            noteColorsToFile(noteColors, strListTemp);
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
                        {
                            keyBindMethode(ref keyBinds, keyAmount, check, answer, repeatOnce);
                            keyBindsToFile(keyBinds, strListTemp);
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
                        {
                            noteAmountMethode(check, ref noteAmount, keyAmount);
                            if (noteAmount != "random")
                            {
                                intNoteAmount = Convert.ToInt16(noteAmount);
                            }
                            valuesToFile(keyAmount, noteAmount, soundEffect, strListTemp);
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
                        {
                            soundEffectMethode(check, ref soundEffect, player, answer);
                            if (soundEffect != "silent")
                            {
                                player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundEffect);
                            }
                            valuesToFile(keyAmount, noteAmount, soundEffect, strListTemp);
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D5)
                        {
                            noteColorMethode(keyAmount, strTemp, ref noteColors, backgroundColor);
                            noteColorsToFile(noteColors, strListTemp);
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
                        {
                            bakcgroundColorMethode(check, ref backgroundColor, strTemp);
                            for (int I = 0; i < noteColors.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (noteColors[i] == backgroundColor)
                                {
                                    check = false;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!check)
                            {
                                noteColorMethode(keyAmount, strTemp, ref noteColors, backgroundColor);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D7)
                        {
                            if (displayKeybinds)
                            {
                                displayKeybinds = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                displayKeybinds = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //if the right keys are pressed and soundEffect is not "silent", a sound effect will play
                if (soundEffect != "silent")
                {
                    player.Play();
                }
            }
        }
        //the next methodes are the user assigned settings, most have if statements with bool checks that loop untill the input is valid
        static void keyAmountMethode(bool check, string strTemp, ref int keyAmount)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            while (check)
            {
                //assigns keyAmount
                Console.WriteLine("How many keys do you play with? \"1-20\"");
                strTemp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                //if it is between 1 and 20
                if (strTemp != "" && strTemp.All(char.IsDigit) && Convert.ToInt32(strTemp) >= 1 && Convert.ToInt32(strTemp) <= 20)
                {
                    keyAmount = Convert.ToInt16(strTemp);
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
        static void keyBindMethode(ref List<ConsoleKeyInfo> keyBinds, int keyAmount, bool check, string answer, bool repeatOnce)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            bool repeatKeyBinder = true;
            while (repeatKeyBinder)
            {
                //adds keys to keyBinds untill it has the same amount as keyAmount because every keybind should represent a key
                Console.WriteLine("What are your preffered keybinds?");
                for (int i = 0; i < keyAmount; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nKey" + (i + 1) + ":");
                    keyBinds.Add(Console.ReadKey());
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i * 2 + 2);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
                    Console.Write(keyBinds[i].Key);
                }
                //asks if the keybinds are right while still displaying them and repeats the binding if they are not
                while (check)
                {
                    //repeat once is so "Are these keybinds correct?" and "The input was invalid!" aren't spammed
                    if (repeatOnce)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nAre these keybinds correct? \"yes\" or \"no\"");
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, keyAmount * 2 + 5);
                    }
                    answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, keyAmount * 2 + 5);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
                    if (answer == "yes" || answer == "no")
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (repeatOnce)
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, keyAmount * 2 + 4);
                            Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                            repeatOnce = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                check = true;
                if (answer == "yes")
                {
                    repeatKeyBinder = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if the keybinding is repeated, keyBinds should be reset
                    keyBinds = new List<ConsoleKeyInfo>();
                }
                repeatOnce = true;
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        static void noteAmountMethode(bool check, ref string noteAmount, int keyAmount)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            while (check)
            {
                //assigns noteAmount (the amount of 'notes' displayed simultanieusly\the amount of keys to press)
                Console.WriteLine("How many notes should come on the screen simultaneously? \"equal or lower to your key amount\" or \"random\"");
                noteAmount = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                //if its "random" or between 1 and keyAmount
                if (noteAmount == "random" || noteAmount != "" && noteAmount.All(char.IsDigit) && Convert.ToInt32(noteAmount) >= 1 && Convert.ToInt32(noteAmount) <= keyAmount)
                {
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
        static void soundEffectMethode(bool check, ref string soundEffect, System.Media.SoundPlayer player, string answer)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            bool previeuw = true;
            while (check)
            {
                //assigns soundEffect
                Console.WriteLine("What sound effect would you like to hear? \"clap\", \"drop\", \"pop\", \"tik\" or \"silent\"");
                soundEffect = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (soundEffect == "clap" || soundEffect == "drop" || soundEffect == "pop" || soundEffect == "tik")
                {
                    soundEffect = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\sounds\\" + soundEffect + ".wav";
                    check = false;
                }
                else if (soundEffect == "silent")
                {
                    check = false;
                    previeuw = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            check = true;
            //asks if the user wants to hear it
            while (previeuw)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like a previeuw of the sound effect? \"yes\" or \"no\"");
                answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (answer == "yes" || answer == "no")
                {
                    previeuw = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            previeuw = true;
            //if so, asks the user if he wants to keep it(ends the methode) or not(repeats the methode)
            if (answer == "yes")
            {
                player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundEffect);
                player.Play();
                while (check)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to keep this sound effect? \"yes\" or \"no\"");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    if (answer == "yes" || answer == "no")
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                    }
                }
                check = true;
                if (answer == "no")
                {
                    soundEffectMethode(check, ref soundEffect, player, answer);
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
        static void noteColorMethode(int keyAmount, string strTemp, ref List<ConsoleColor> noteColors, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What are your preffered note colors? for example \"Blue\" or \"DarkGray\"");
            //adds colors to noteColors
            for (int i = 0; i < keyAmount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNote" + (i + 1) + ":");
                strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Enum.TryParse(strTemp, out ConsoleColor result) && strTemp != Convert.ToString(backgroundColor))
                {
                    noteColors.Add((ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), strTemp));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    i--;
                    Console.WriteLine("What are your preffered note colors? for example \"Blue\" or \"DarkGray\"");
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
        static void bakcgroundColorMethode(bool check, ref ConsoleColor backgroundColor, string strTemp)
        {
            //changes the backgroundcolor
            Console.Clear();
            while (check)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What color do you want the background to have? \"Blue\" or \"DarkGray\"");
                strTemp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (Enum.TryParse(strTemp, out ConsoleColor result) && strTemp != "White" && strTemp != "Red")
                {
                    backgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), strTemp);
                    Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid!");
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }

        //these methodes save most of the settings to text files
        static void valuesToFile(int keyAmount, string noteAmount, string soundEffect, List<string> strListTemp)
        {
            strListTemp = new List<string>();
            strListTemp = new List<string> { Convert.ToString(keyAmount), noteAmount, soundEffect };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\values.txt", strListTemp);
        }
        static void keyBindsToFile(List<ConsoleKeyInfo> keyBinds, List<string> strListTemp)
        {
            strListTemp = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < keyBinds.Count; i++)
            {
                //ConsoleKeyInfos need a .KeyChar, the value of a .Key and modifiers, but I want the modifiers to always be false, so I don't need to save them
                strListTemp.Add(Convert.ToString(keyBinds[i].KeyChar) + " " + Convert.ToString((int)keyBinds[i].Key));
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\keyBinds.txt", strListTemp);
        }
        static void noteColorsToFile(List<ConsoleColor> noteColors, List<string> strListTemp)
        {
            strListTemp = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < noteColors.Count; i++)
            {
                strListTemp.Add(Convert.ToString(noteColors[i]));
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings\\noteColors.txt", strListTemp);
        }
    }
}
```

Especially the performance of the check if every right key is pressed is not too great.
It works but you have to be precise.
If anything is unclear, be sure to give me a comment.
I would be thankful for every tip you guys can throw at me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few of the things I noticed:

Start learning OOP(Object Oriented Programming).  The .net library and the languages that use it are designed to follow OOP.  With that in mind, the game itself should be in a separate class and many of your functions can be broken down into smaller ones.

The file names.  You are concatenating them on the fly each time you need one, which is at least twice for each one.  Put them in variables and concatenate them once.

Try to get into the habit of using the interpolation operator(`$`) to concatenate strings.  It is much easier to use and maintain.

The block to check which key is pressed is at best kludgy.  I'm surprised it even works.  You're checking the console for a new key press on each condition that you're checking for.  It seems to me it would make more sense to store a key press then check it against each condition.

Answer (score 3):

A small contribution. I noticed that you would have blocks of code like this...

```
if (File.Exists("settings.txt")
{
    string settings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt");
    ...
}
```

I'm quite a big hater of nesting, if it can be avoided so I would suggest to do it this way instead

```
// check to see if the file exists. If not, throw an exception.
if (!File.Exists("settings.txt") throw new Exception("The settings file could not be found.");

// grab the contents of the file
string setttings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt");
```

I would also continue on this block and say that you should notj just blindly accept the contents of the `settings.txt` file and you should always lean towards not trusting external input, especially if it has the opportunity to be tampered with (like in this case a malformed settings file).

At the bare minimum you can  do

```
// check if the settings file is empty
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(settings) throw new Exception("The settings file is empty.");
```

In order to reduce the complexity of dealing with formatting, parsing and validation there are plenty of string formats to represent objects and configurations (JSON, XML, INF, etc)

- INF has been a long standing "Windows" format
- XML is basically frowned upon these days but used to be very popular
- JSON is becoming very popular (I would recommend to go with this at a beginner level)

Just as an example the string would appear like

```
"Settings":
{
    "Console":
    {
        "ForegroundColor": "Grey",
        "BackgroundColor": "Black",
        "Encoding": "UTF-8"
    }
    "Game":
    {
        "Difficulty": 10.5,
        "Autosave": false
    }
}
```

and this would be very easily turned into an object in C# (just grab the library for it), which would then allow you write easy to read code like so...

```
boolean autosave = settings.Game.Autosave;
```